# mkvirtualenv virt command thinks virt directory already exists

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am trying to run the command `mkvirtualenv virt` from the Windows 10 command line and am getting the error `ERROR: virtualenv "virt" already exists` even though there is no content in the directory that I am running this command from. Any ideas what may be happening?

Answer (score 0):

`mkvirtualenv` is a part of `virtualenvwrapper` — a virtualev manager that creates all environments not in the current directory but in `~/.virtualenvs` so you can only have one `virt` there. If you want a virtualev in the current directory use `virtualev` but then you loose all the power of virtualenvwrapper.